# Powershell script to check if all files from a list of files exist in given folder folder

Tags: arrays, powershell, directory, filenames

I need to write a powershell script, input a list of file names and check a given folder. I need it to echo if all files from list are present in the folder( if not which are not) and the other way around - are all files in the folder listed in the inputted list of file names.

Im new to powershell, just finished my first script to rename all files in a folder and I dont have a clue how to input a list and iterate thgrough it while checking file names in the folder.

I've managed to write smomething like this:

```
$Dir2 = "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\testDir2"
$filenames = 'a.txt', 'b.txt', 'c.txt', 'd.txt'
foreach ($filename in $filenames) {
$found=$false; 
Get-ChildItem -Path $Dir2 -Recurse | ForEach-Object {if($filename -eq $_.Name) {Write-Host $filename ' Ok' -foregroundcolor green; $found=$true;CONTINUE }$found=$false;} -END {if($found -ne $true){ Write-Host $filename ' missing' -foregroundcolor red}}
}
```

I still need to check the other way around + I need to somehow convert rows from excel sheet to the list of filenames

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I have the code that suits my needs:
(list of files is given in a file it can be csv)

```
$Dir2 = 'C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\testDir2'
$filenames=Get-Content $Dir2\filenamesnoext.csv
foreach ($filename in $filenames) {
$found=$false; 
Get-ChildItem -Path $Dir2 -Recurse | ForEach-Object {if($filename -eq $_.BaseName) {Write-Host 'FILE ' $filename ' Ok' -foregroundcolor green; $found=$true;CONTINUE }$found=$false;} -END {if($found -ne $true){ Write-Host 'FILE ' $filename ' missing in the folder' -foregroundcolor red}}
}
Get-ChildItem -Path $Dir2 -Recurse | ForEach-Object  {$found=$false; foreach ($filename in $filenames) {if($filename -eq $_.BaseName) {Write-Host 'FILE ' $_.BaseName ' was found on the list' -foregroundcolor cyan; $found=$true;BREAK }} if($found -ne $true){ Write-Host 'FILE ' $_.BaseName ' missing on the list of files' -foregroundcolor Magenta} }
```

Answer (score 1):

To retrieve the list from a text file, use the [`Get-Content` cmdlet]:

```
$FileList = Get-Content -Path .\myFileList.txt
```

To retrieve the files in the folder, use the [`Get-ChildItem` cmdlet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849800.aspx):

```
$Files = Get-ChildItem -Path C:\path\to\folder -File
```

Grab the file names with [`Select-Object`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849895.aspx):

```
$Files = $Files |Select-Object -Property Name
```

And finally compare the two lists with [`Compare-Object`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849941.aspx):

```
$Discrepancies = @(Compare-Object $FileList $Files)
```

If `Compare-Object` didn't return anything, there will have been no difference between the two lists:

```
if($Discrepancies.Count -eq 0)
{
    Write-Host "Everything is as expected!"
}
```

Comment: hmm Compare-Object did not return anything, but there should be diffrences in my test list and test folder

Comment: @AdamWróblewski Use `Compare-Object $FileList $Files -IncludeEqual` to see which comparisons match up, may give you a hint

Answer (score 1):

Here is another version if someone finds it more readable (no skipping loop iterations, getting file names only once):

```
    $folder = 'D:\stuff'
    $files = @(
        "one.txt",
        "two.txt"
    )
    Write-Host "Folder: $folder."
    # Get only files and only their names
    $folderFiles = Get-ChildItem -Path $folder -Recurse -File -Name
    foreach ($f in $files) {
        if ($folderFiles -contains $f) { 
            Write-Host "File $f was found." -foregroundcolor green
        } else { 
            Write-Host "File $f was not found!" -foregroundcolor red 
        }
    }
```